# Tried clone files from Git repo. Only (.git) folder is downloaded and it has nothing

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I am new to `Git`.

I am in `Windows7` and using `CygWin`. Below us the clone command I tried.

```
 git clone http://git.fadv.com/abg/abg.git GIT1/
```

I got only HEAD files.  Below are the folders and files I have got..

```
hooks
info
objects
refs
confil - file
description-file
HEAD-file
```

I Googled the issue. No where I find the what is the issue and what is the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the git repo is properly set and you have the permission to clone it? If it's on github can you browse the repository from web-console?

Comment: Yaah, I have the permission. I did clone using `eclipse` and `NetBeans` IDE. It works fine. I got the repo files. There is some issue with `pull`. So I want to check with normal commands...

Comment: So that means you are all fine now? Which platform you use btw? For Windows and Mac you can give their native clients a try.

Comment: can you show us which commands you used to clone the repo?

Comment: @Chronial I have updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: @intellidiot Please check the question. It is edited.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have all the files. Probably the default branch(master) you are on has no files. Try:

git branch
and then try to checkout a branch you know has files in it.

It should fix it.